# Skipped the first dragon encounter - now what?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I wanted to help Gerud in Riverwood who asked me to warn the Jarl of Whiterun about the dragon attack, so when I get there I warn him and he immediately sends me off to get the dragonstone.

So I go on kicking ass until I get to the last guy who is in a tomb in front of the first dragon word of power. Thing is that he also has dragon power and kills me in an instant. After I saw that the first dragon encounter is before that (so I can get a dragon soul and activate my first word of power having the chance of killing the bastard) I get back to Whiterun to see if I can still access the first dragon encounter but I'm failing miserably. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: That's not dragon power, it's a frost spell. Get some magic and/or frost resistance.

Comment: And or get a companion -- the archer in Riverwood will join you after you help him out.

Answer (score 10):

If I remember correctly, the first encounter where you have to kill a dragon is **after** that quest where you need to get the dragon stone from Bleak Falls Barrow. The jarl wanted you to get it in order to prove that you are worthy of their trust or something, right?

If you cant defeat that "boss" draugr in the tomb at all (even with preparation such as potions), all you can do is leave the quest alone and do some other quests / kill things to level up a bit and come back later when you're stronger.

Comment: thats exacly what Im doing right now :P

Answer (score 0):

Ok reffering to Whiterun. If you never kill the dragon that the jarl wants you to kill. No dragons will ever appear to you in the game afterward. Ive been playing for 30 levels I believe with no dragon encounters. Also you may not kill the first dragon which I believe is alduin, until you go into savengard...correct my spelling...on  a special dragonborn mission. Which I completed on my first character.

Answer (score -3):

I believe he may be referring to the dragon attack that saved his sweet bippy from being beheaded. I am not sure if you can kill that dragon. (I'm sure someone will correct me if I am wrong). I do know however that if you return to Helgen the dragon is gone, and there is not much left but burned out rubble, so if you want to try to kill that dragon you will need to restart the game as a new player.

Greg

Comment: Barring console commands, you don't actually have any way to damage Alduin in Helgen.